# A Question About Probability Inspired By A Textbook

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A book I've been reading, about probability, has stated that probability is the ratio of the number desired outcomes, to the total of number of outcomes, given that each outcome has the same chance of occurring.

My question is, what should one do then, if you want to find the probability that an outcome occurs, and each outcome has a different probability of occurring? Let's say for example, there are 3 outcomes X, Y and Z, and X has a 40% chance of occurring, Y has a 45% chance occurring, and Z has a 15% chance of occurring. How would I find the probability of that X occurs? **And could you why is this method, to find the probability of X, correct, given that probability is the ratio of the number desired outcomes, to the total of number of outcomes.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probability is not _defined_ as that ratio.  Instead, probability _happens_ to be that ratio, in case each of the (finite number of) outcomes is equally probable.  If they are not equally probable, then you just sum up the ones you want.  E.g. in your example $Prob(X \, or \, Y) = 85\%$.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the probability of occurrence is already given in the question. It is $40/100=0.4$. Since there are total 3 events $X,Y$ & $Z$. And $X$ has $40$% chance of occurrence, so probability of occurring $X$ is $P(X)=40/(40+45+15)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous definitions of probability, including *subjective probability* of a *single* event, as in "What's the probability of rain tomorrow?"

If this (unnamed) textbook is by a reputable author, he or she was certainly giving that "frequentist" definition *in the context of a certain class of problems*, such as drawing a white ball out of an urn with balls of multiple colors.

I recommend the OP consult any of the many dozens of excellent textbooks and websites on the foundations of probability and statistics.  After all, this problem has been address (and solved) long long ago.